# Sum of an array of numbers, separated by commas in 1 cell, only if there are at least 5 elements

Tags: excel-formula

1. I need the sum of an array of elements in the same cell.
2. They are separated by commas.
3. If there are <5 elements then DON'T calculate the sum of that cell.

Example:

```
cell 1A: 2,1,2,3,1  cell 1B: 9 (the sum)

cell 2A: 1, 2       cell 2B: -- (nothing as there are less than five elements).
```

I have tried to explain myself. Hope it's clear.

Comment: Hi. I'm a newbie so I separate the array of numbers into separate cells. Then I add them up with the SUM formula but I do it manually. ie: I skip cells where there aren't 5 elements. As I say, I'm sure there must be a way.

Answer (score 3):

I asked a similar question here:

[Old Question](https://superuser.com/questions/1057634/summing-a-list-of-values)

But you have an additional requirement, so try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function SumWithin(s As String) As Variant
    If s = "" Then
        SumWithin = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    If InStr(1, s, ",") = 0 Then
        SumWithin = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    arry = Split(s, ",")
    If UBound(arry) < 4 Then
        SumWithin = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    For Each a In arry
        SumWithin = SumWithin + CDbl(a)
    Next a
End Function
```

Some examples:

[image]

This approach avoids all the extra cells required for the typical *Text-to-Columns* approach.
It **is** possible to do this without VBA, but it involves array formulas.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the name manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) to trick excel into reading the list as an array, I called my named range "valueArray":

`=EVALUATE("{"&SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!$A2," ","")&"}")`

Note that there is no absolute referencing for the row argument and that it starts on the same row as the data (to align the first use of the array correctly).

You could just reference `Sheet1!$A2` directly being wrapped in `EVALUATE()` and the curly brackets but `SUBSTITUTE()` has been used to make sure the data won't be compromised by spaces.

[image: Name Manager]

Now that you have the array, you can perform your logical on it with ease, if an error is thrown or the cell is blank when you expect a result, it is likely that one of the values hasn't parsed as a number (perhaps a letter or two is in there):

`=IF(COUNT(valueArray)>4,SUM(valueArray),"")`

[image: Example]