Single Excel cell having comma separated numeric values need to be added by VBA
I require to add  the values in a single excel cell which having comma separated two numeric values (i.e) For example on cell (i, 30) has the values as 2,1 and  I want this to be get added as result as 3 using vba
Currently I don't have any idea to add this up, if anyone sort me out which will be very helpful.
Sub combination(i As Integer)

Dim fvs_temp8 As Workbook

Dim rc As Integer
    rc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Dim all As Workbook
        Set all = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "Reference_files\AMP Template_V1.0_V2.0_V2.1_09052023.xlsx")

        Set fvs_temp8 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "Reference_files\Template_v_24062020.xls")

'extra discount's

Dim txtstr As String

Dim am22 As Integer

Dim result As Integer

txtstr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 30).Value

am22 = WorksheetFunction.Replace(txtstr, ",", "+")

result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(am22)


If result = 3 Then

Dim cr201 As Integer
        cr201 = fvs_temp3.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        all.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Additions").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A84:DZ84").Copy
        fvs_temp3.Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & cr201 + 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial
End If

End Sub


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486462/sum-of-an-array-of-numbers-separated-by-commas-in-1-cell-only-if-there-are-at

So you want to check if numeric and then add?
Function sumCSVNumbers(val As String)
    Dim arr As Variant:  arr = Split(val, ",")
    If IsNumeric(arr(0)) = True And IsNumeric(arr(1)) = True Then sumCSVNumbers = Application.Sum(arr(0), arr(1))
End Function


This only works for two values; you can create a loop to go through all parts of arr if you want to sum additional values, checking isnumeric() for each part, or even sum up only the numeric parts in case something does come through with a string.

I think that best method would be to walk the array (your second option).  That way, if there is a non-numeric value, you can then generate an Error message that will communicate clearly to the user what the invalid value is.

@FrankBall aside from mentioning it as an option, it also depends on what the poster is actually looking for.  I posted a solution that allows for some quick debugging (e.g., debug.print arr(1) after the split, in case they need to test, and we don't see how the source data is beyond 2,1 being written out.  Given they had the concept for the rest of the code, I assumed providing the comment-level of details is enough to help them move forward, rather than going through the for i = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr) if it was not necessary.  I appreciate the chime in on error handling!

Thanks Cyril, much appreciated for your response. It's working really. Kudos boss!

@SeenuGochalam if this has resolved your issue, please mark the checkbox to the left of my response for "Answered".

Yep it's done thanks mate!

Another solution:
Function sumCSVNumbers(val As String) As Double
  sumCSVNumbers = Application.Evaluate("SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(""" & val & ""","","")),0))")
End Function

It uses the power Excel functions to process arrays.

This solution processes any number of numbers; non-numbers are ignored.

A formula based alternative may be this; (prepared on Excel 2010)
=SUMPRODUCT((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1& ",";",";REPT(" ";255));1+(ROW(A$1:A$999)-1)*255;255)) & "0")/10)


